# Non-existent instance in Game Maker

Tags: 2d, software-engineering, game-maker

I'm currently trying to make the fire object (created by the fireball) stick to the enemy, by specifying the enemy type and its id. I'm getting the following error:

"Unable to find any instance for object index '-4' name undefined".
Here's my fireball [collision with enemy] code:

```
var sp=other.speed
var dir=other.direction
var oi=other.id
var on=object_get_name(other)
with (instance_create(other.x-lengthdir_x(new_push_amount, pd),other.y-lengthdir_y(new_push_amount, pd),fire))
{
speed = sp
direction = dir
enemyid = oi
enemyname=on
}
```

And here is the Create,

```
enemyname = ""
enemyid = 0
```

and the Step events of fireball:

```
speed = instance_find(enemyname,enemyid).speed
direction = instance_find(enemyname,enemyid).direction
```

Maybe I'm using the wrong functional to get the instance... In any case, help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing. `object_get_name` needs object index, not instance index, like this:

```
var on = object_get_name(other.object_index); // or maybe (other.id).object_index, I don't have ability for check it now
```

Second. You must check what `instance_find` returned. Because instance may not exists.

```
var obj = instance_find(enemyname, enemyid);
if instance_exists(obj)
{
    speed = obj.speed;
    direction = obj.direction;
}
```

Third. `instance_find` needs `object_index`, not an object's name (which is a string) and index (which is not equal `id`).

I don't understand why you don't use just `id` of the instance.

```
var spd = other.speed;
var dir = other.direction;
var inst_id = other.id;

with instance_create(other.x-lengthdir_x(new_push_amount, pd), other.y-lengthdir_y(new_push_amount, pd), fire)
{
    speed = spd;
    direction = dir;
    enemyid = inst_id;
}
```

Or same, but less lines:

```
var obj = instance_create(other.x-lengthdir_x(new_push_amount, pd), other.y-lengthdir_y(new_push_amount, pd), fire);
obj.speed = other.speed;
obj.direction = other.direction;
obj.enemyid = other.id;
```

And `Step End` event (not `Step`, otherwise there will be a lag):

```
if instance_exists(enemyid)
{
    speed = enemyid.speed;
    direction = enemyid.direction;
}
else
{
    instance_destroy(); // ? I don't know, is need you it or not
    // but anyway don't forget to destroy object
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked! I took the time and got into it, it's been long since I last used Game Maker. Also, sorry for the long response.